# Omit 'Pattern not found' error message in Vim script

Tags: vim, vi

I added a function in my .vimrc that's just few search and replace commands. However if one of the patterns is not found I get an error message that I need to enter through. How can I suppress this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can either use `:silent` or `:silent!` as a prefix to any command *or* you can add the 'e' option to the substitute, which is often easier.

```
:%s/x/y/ge
:silent! %s/x/y/g
:silent %s/x/y/g
```

For more information, see

```
:help :silent
:help :s_flags
```

The information on the `e` flag is a few paragraphs down from the `:s_flags` help.

Comment: @DrAI Can this be configured in `vimrc`? i.e. can I just do `%s` and it shall pick up the `e` flag?

Comment: @Krishna Not as far as I know.  I guess you could come up with a mapping that added the silent on the start, e.g. `cnoremap %s silent %s`, but it might have unintended consequences (e.g. if you type %s somewhere other than at the start of the command).

Answer (score 2):

You might use silent:

```
:silent %s/x/y/g
```

or, if you need to do string manipulation to determine the strings to search and replace:

```
exec ":silent %s/x/" . varName . "/g"
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that `silent` only works in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little bit off topic but i found this thread when searching for solutions for "search pattern not found" errors in vim, when i wanted to search for the next occurence in vim. The following map omits the error when pressing 'n'

map n :silent! /

Answer (score 1):

this also works for global operation

```
:silent g/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the :he :silent thing can be used to suppress those errors?